# Error:Not Found: /media/media/photos/e.jpg in django

Tags: django

I've deployed one project In web server. our project everything fine but i unable print image on profile page .in our local system working fine but in server error getting Not Found: /media/media/photos/e.jpg in django.

models.py

```
class Matr(models.Model):
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/photos/', null=True, 
blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
MIDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

profile.html

```
{% if user.matr.photo %}
<img src="{{ user.matr.photo.url }}" width="330">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `user.matr` or `user.math` ?

Comment: matr only i enterd